# Need to Scrape text with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html

Can anyone help with how i can scrap just the text below from this code using beautifulsoup.

"Disappointed coach Bert van Marwijk said Australia have to find the last part of the puzzle if they are to stay in the World Cup after a 1-1 draw with Denmark on Thursday. Australia captain Mile Jedinak hit a VAR-assisted penalty to earn the Socceroos first point in Russia after Christian Eriksens opener, giving Australia"

```
<a href="website" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onmouseover="ddrivetip('<em>Thu, 21 Jun 2018</em> <br/> Disappointed coach Bert van Marwijk said Australia have to find the last part of the puzzle if they are to stay in the World Cup after a 1-1 draw with Denmark on Thursday. Australia captain Mile Jedinak hit a VAR-assisted penalty to earn the Socceroos first point in Russia after Christian Eriksens opener, giving Australia []')" ;="" onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">Australias Van Marwijk says last part of puzzle missing at World Cup</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<a href="website" 
    target="_blank" 
    rel="nofollow" 
    onmouseover="ddrivetip('<em>Thu, 21 Jun 2018</em> <br/> Disappointed coach Bert van Marwijk said Australia have to find the last part of the puzzle if they are to stay in the World Cup after a 1-1 draw with Denmark on Thursday. Australia captain Mile Jedinak hit a VAR-assisted penalty to earn the Socceroos first point in Russia after Christian Eriksens opener, giving Australia []')" ;="" 
    onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">
    Australias Van Marwijk says last part of puzzle missing at World Cup
</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    attr_text = a.attrs['onmouseover'][43:-4]                                                                                                                                     
    print(attr_text + a.text)
```

**Output**

```
Disappointed coach Bert van Marwijk said Australia have to find the
last part of the puzzle if they are to stay in the World Cup after a 
1-1 draw with Denmark on Thursday. Australia captain Mile Jedinak hit 
a VAR-assisted penalty to earn the Socceroos first point in Russia 
after Christian Eriksens opener, giving Australia Australias Van 
Marwijk says last part of puzzle missing at World Cup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `a.attrs['onmouseover']`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
s = """<a href="website" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onmouseover="ddrivetip('<em>Thu, 21 Jun 2018</em> <br/> Disappointed coach Bert van Marwijk said Australia have to find the last part of the puzzle if they are to stay in the World Cup after a 1-1 draw with Denmark on Thursday. Australia captain Mile Jedinak hit a VAR-assisted penalty to earn the Socceroos first point in Russia after Christian Eriksens opener, giving Australia []')" ;="" onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">Australias Van Marwijk says last part of puzzle missing at World Cup</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
val = soup.a.attrs['onmouseover']
m = re.search("\((.*?)\)", val)
if m:
    print(m.group())
```

**Output:**

```
('<em>Thu, 21 Jun 2018</em> <br/> Disappointed coach Bert van Marwijk said Australia have to find the last part of the puzzle if they are to stay in the World Cup after a 1-1 draw with Denmark on Thursday. Australia captain Mile Jedinak hit a VAR-assisted penalty to earn the Socceroos first point in Russia after Christian Eriksens opener, giving Australia []')
```